# How to download a file in a branch from a Git repo using Azure DevOps REST Api?

Tags: git, azure-devops

For a file in the master branch I can use the following URL - `http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TFSProject/_apis/git/repositories/GitRepo/items?path=FilePath&api-version=4.1`

But what if I need to download a file from the branch?

P.S.

I know perfectly well that I can clone a git repository. I need REST API specifically.

**EDIT 1**

So, I tried the following code:

```
$Url = "http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/code/_apis/git/repositories/xyz/itemsbatch?api-version=4.1"
$Body = @"
{
    "itemDescriptors": [
    {
        "path": "/Bootstrap.ps1",
        "version": "shelve/vsts",
        "versionType": "branch"
    }]
}
"@
Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri $Url -OutFile $PSScriptRoot\AutomationBootstrapImpl.ps1 -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $Body
```

It succeeds, but the generated file is not exactly what I expected:

```
{"count":1,"value":[[{"objectId":"ceb9d83e971abdd3326d67e25b20c2cb1b4943e2","gitObjectType":"blob","commitId":"d4a039914002613e775f6274aee6489b244a42a7","path":"/bootstrap.ps1","url":"http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/code/_apis/git/repositories/xyz/items/bootstrap.ps1?versionType=Branch&version=shelve%2Fvsts&versionOptions=None"}]]}
```

However, it gives the URL I can use to get the file from branch - `http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/code/_apis/git/repositories/xyz/items/bootstrap.ps1?versionType=Branch&version=shelve%2Fvsts&versionOptions=None`

So, here we go:

```
$Url = "http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/code/_apis/git/repositories/xyz/items/bootstrap.ps1?versionType=Branch&version=shelve/vsts"
Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri $Url -OutFile $PSScriptRoot\AutomationBootstrapImpl.ps1
```

And it works as expected. But I still do not know what is the name of this API method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [GetItems Batch API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#gitversiontype) does include a [`versionType` of type `GitVersionType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#gitversiontype):

> Version type (branch, tag, or commit). Determines how Id is interpreted

So if you add to your REST API URL the attributes:

```
?versionType=Branch&version=myBranch
```

That should be enough to get the items from a specific branch

As the OP mentions, it gives an intermediate URL which points to:

```
http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items/{path}?versionType=Branch&version=myBranch
```

That means:

- it uses as expected `?versionType=Branch&version=myBranch`
- But it uses [`_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items` Items Get API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0), not `_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/itemsbatch`

Comment: Please, see my edit. Although not really it, I will accept it, since it does lead to the answer. Still, if you could modify it and mention the API method that does it, it would be terrific.

Comment: @mark I have edited the answer accordingly, and added a link to the relevant API.

Comment: Thank you. I hope nobody will be confused by you mentioning the concrete values that are specific to my particular environment, like `code`, `xyz`, `bootstrap.ps1` and `shelve/vsts`

Comment: @mark Good point. I have edited the question to only use placeholders, instead of the specific values.