# Download a file from Azure git

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, invoke-restmethod

I'm trying to download a file with the Azure Devops Rest API using Powershell's Invoke-RestMethod.  It always seems to download from the main branch and ignores my branch specification

The urls I'm using are

```
invoke-restmethod -uri "https://dev.azure.com/company/xxx/_apis/git/repositories/xxx/items?path=%2Fpom.xml&commitOrBranch=main&api-version=6.0" -Method Get -ContentType "application/text" -Headers $headers
```

and

```
invoke-restmethod -uri "https://dev.azure.com/company/xxx/_apis/git/repositories/xxx/items?path=%2Fpom.xml&commitOrBranch=branchName&api-version=6.0" -Method Get -ContentType "application/text" -Headers $headers
```

How do I specify the branch?  The documentation doesn't provide any details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a file in a branch from a Git repo using Azure DevOps REST Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54228312/how-to-download-a-file-in-a-branch-from-a-git-repo-using-azure-devops-rest-api)

Comment: This looks like an older version of the API which seems totally different.  They seem to change the api frequently, and the documentation only includes a very brief description of the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below commandlet.

Just modified the below based on the question to download a pom.xml from the `<BranchName>`

```
invoke-restmethod -uri "https://dev.azure.com/company/xxx/_apis/git/repositories/xxx/items/pom.xml?versionType=Branch&version=<BranchName>" -Method Get -ContentType "application/text" -Headers $headers
```

Comment: Yes, I had already figured this out based on additional research.  I don't understand all the inconsistent documentation on this api, but this was the solution