# How to get file content of repositories in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, rest

could someone tell a way to get file contents through rest api in azure devops?
I tried in this way but it isnt getting proper results.

https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/sourceProviders/Git/filecontents?serviceEndpointId=&repository=&commitOrBranch=main&path=/&api-version=6.0-preview.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a file in a branch from a Git repo using Azure DevOps REST Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54228312/how-to-download-a-file-in-a-branch-from-a-git-repo-using-azure-devops-rest-api)

Answer (score 2):

The URL I have posted above works..I had given wrong input for source provider. It should have been TfsGit.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in this format `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/sourceProviders/{providerName}/filecontents?api-version=5.0-preview.1`

Service endpoint should be TFGit as per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/source-providers/get-file-contents?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Comment: Also found this is working, in case you just need file contents

https://dev.azure.com/{{Organization}}/{{ProjectName}//_apis/git/repositories/{{RepoName}}/items?versionDescriptor.version={{BranchName}}&path={{FilePathwithName}}&api-version=5.0 

It downloads the content, we need to pipe that to output file or any object based on your  programming language.

Comment: What exactly is {providerName}?

Comment: @Mik Provider is the version control service. In my case it is "tfsGit"
example: https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganization/MyProject/_apis/sourceProviders/tfsGit/filecontents?repository=repname&path=/directory1/file.txt&api-version=6.0-preview.1