# Can we use SQL scripts (Develop hub) during pipeline creation (Integrate hub) in azure synapse?

Tags: azure-synapse

I want to use my *SQL script* (present under **Develop** hub) file inside a *Pipeline* (present under **Integrate** hub). Currently I do not see any Activities available solving this purpose.

There is one *Script* activity under *General* section which only have a Query & NonQuery option, not for referring any SQL script file created earlier.

Is that feature available at all in Azure Synapse Analytics? Can we refer to *SQL script* by some other means?

Comment: you can copy/paste your script into the task. Do you have any reason for wanting to keep it external? An ever better approach is to create your script as a stored procedure inside the database so your source code is kept with your data

Answer (score 0):

If your Synapse workspace is paired with Azure DevOps then I imagine it’s easy to get the file content with a REST API call (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68543594/how-to-get-file-content-of-repositories-in-azure-devops)).  However then you have to parse the file as GO is not supported by the Script activity.  ADF / Synapse Pipeline functions do not support a RegEx style split eg word boundary and GO (\bGO\b) so it starts to get kind of fiddly.  I had some success with replace and uriComponent functions.

However you would be better of using Stored Procedures and the [Stored Proc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure) activity in Synapse Pipelines - much simpler implementation.