# In Azure Devops, can we enforce a readme file to a list of repos with certain wiki links?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

We have several wiki pages created in our Azure Devops which will help developers to onboard their applications with certain information.

Since we need to manage a huge team, its challenging to share the wiki details to new new teams which are onboarding.

As a solution we are looking for some enforcement policy in Azure Devops which will help us.

- A common readme file with those wiki links are onboarded to all the new repos going to be created.
- The common readme file with those wiki links are imported to all the  existing repos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a solution we are looking for some enforcement policy in Azure
> Devops which will help us.

I'm afraid there's no such enforcement policy can help meet your requirements.

> The common readme file with those wiki links are imported to all the
> existing repos

However, adding the file to your existing repositories can be achieved by using [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP#add-a-text-file):

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?api-version=5.1
```

For example, I have file: `MD_Folder/wiki_links.md` in repo `testfile1`. And I want to add this file to other repos.
Here's a sample script I used in pipeline to add the file to different repos.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      import os
      import base64
      import requests
      import json
      
      #get file content from file_path and return it as base64
      
      def get_file_content(file_path):
          with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
              content = f.read()
          #base64 encode the content
          content = str(base64.b64encode(content))
          #remove the b' and ' from the content
          content = content[2:-1]
          # print(content)
          return content
      
      def get_branch_object_id(organization_name, project_name, personal_access_token, repo_name, branch_name):
          url = "https://dev.azure.com/"+organization_name+"/"+project_name+"/_apis/git/repositories/"+repo_name+"/refs?api-version=7.0"
      
          payload={}
          headers = {
          'Authorization': 'Basic '+personal_access_token,
          }
      
          response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
          json_response = response.json()
          branches = json_response['value']
          for branch in branches:
              if branch['name'] == 'refs/heads/'+branch_name:
                  # print(branch['objectId'])
                  return branch['objectId']
              else:
                  print("Branch not found")
                  return None
          # print(response.text)
      def push_MD_file_to_repo(organization_name, project_name, personal_access_token, repo_name, branch_name, branch_object_id, remote_path, base64_content):
          url = "https://dev.azure.com/"+organization_name+"/"+project_name+"/_apis/git/repositories/"+repo_name+"/pushes?api-version=5.1"
      
          payload = json.dumps({
          "refUpdates": [
              {
              "name": "refs/heads/"+branch_name+"",
              "oldObjectId": ""+branch_object_id+""
              }
          ],
          "commits": [
              {
              "comment": "Added new wiki MD file.",
              "changes": [
                  {
                  "changeType": "add",
                  "item": {
                      "path": ""+remote_path+""
                  },
                  "newContent": {
                      "content": ""+base64_content+"",
                      "contentType": "base64encoded"
                  }
                  }
              ]
              }
          ]
          })
          headers = {
          'Authorization': 'Basic '+personal_access_token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }
      
          response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
      
          print(response.text)
      
      def push(repo_name):
          organization_name = "{YourOrgName}"
          project_name = "{YourProjectName}"
          personal_access_token = "{YourEncodedPAT}"
          branch_name = "main"
      
          LocalFile = "MD_Folder/wiki_links.md"
          RemoteFile = "Wiki_Folder/wiki_links.md"
      
          base64_content = get_file_content(LocalFile)
          branch_object_id = get_branch_object_id(organization_name, project_name, personal_access_token, repo_name, branch_name)
          push_MD_file_to_repo(organization_name, project_name, personal_access_token, repo_name, branch_name, branch_object_id, RemoteFile, base64_content)
      
      Repositories = "{TargetRepo1},{TargetRepo2},{TargetRepo3}"
      Repositories = Repositories.split(',')
      for repo in Repositories:
          push(repo)
```

Run the pipeline and you will find the file in the path: `Wiki_Folder/wiki_links.md` in the target repos.

[image]
[image]

You can manually enter the target repo and use the comma to separate. Or you could use another script to get the target repo.

Comment: Great. I will checkout this. Also it it possible for the reverse flow like, from all existing repos, I can scan for a directory called "Architecture" and push that directory to a central repo where we are storing all the  "architectures" alone?

Comment: Hi @Vowneee, sorry for the delay response. I'm afraid there's no built-in feature or API can help scan the directories. But we have API that can help get or download a certain file in certain branch. You could refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54228312/how-to-download-a-file-in-a-branch-from-a-git-repo-using-azure-devops-rest-api) for more details.